# Show custom field between product name and star ratings on WooCommerce archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to add a custom field on product cards like below. The code I wrote for this works, but the custom field I added appears above the category name.

I want it to appear between the stars and the product name as I showed in the picture.

[image: i want to show it between stars and product name]

The code I am currently using for this is

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woo_show_product_id', 20);
function woo_show_product_id() {
    global $product;

    echo $product->id;
}
```

---

How can I do that or what adjustment is needed for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [includes/wc-template-hooks.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/ab4a46e32e338cbf33094ab26144744a021a21a9/includes/wc-template-hooks.php) we can find:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_rating', 5 );
```

---

So change priority **from 20**

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woo_show_product_id', 20);
```

**To 4** to display your custom field just before the star ratings

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woo_show_product_id', 4 );
```

**Priority:** Used to specify the order in which the functions associated with a particular action are executed. Lower numbers correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the action. Default value: 10

**Note:** use `$product->get_id();` as of WooCommerce 3.0

---

So to answer your question, you can use

1. via `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title`

```php
function woo_show_product_id() {
    global $product;
    
    // Is a WC product
    if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        // Get Product ID
        echo $product->get_id();
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woo_show_product_id', 4 );
```

**OR**

some other hook from [includes/wc-template-hooks.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/ab4a46e32e338cbf33094ab26144744a021a21a9/includes/wc-template-hooks.php)

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
```

And then you get with priority **11**

2. via `woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title`

```php
function woo_show_product_id() {
    global $product;
    
    // Is a WC product
    if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        // Get Product ID
        echo $product->get_id();
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woo_show_product_id', 11 );
```